Powerpoint not using embedded fonts from pptx file
This is a question for Office Powerpoint masters.
I am using MS Office Professional Plus 2021. I have created a pptx file with fonts embedded. I can see them inside the actual file (font1.fntdata), and also see that the font is inside because of the size of the file. However, when I remove the font from my system and open the pptx file, the embedded font is not used by Powerpoint. Powerpoint even says that the Font is not Available, but it is inside the file.

What could be the reason?
Note: font licence is not an issue, I have tried with freeware fonts and the issue is still the same.

Edit:
I will try to clarify the issue because the only answer so far has misunderstood my question completely, and even people upvoted it, so it is probably my mistake explaining the issue.
I have a pptx file (e.g. https://mega.nz/file/pYIWxBRB#FlGKlg1Ho9bzghITRcK6m_lNW1e9ms7ZVK72aOIrxyI) with fonts embedded. If you check the contents of the file, a font is embedded. To avoid confusion, let us say that I did not create this file, I got it from someone that had the font in their computer and saved the file with the fonts embedded. The file should look like this:

Now, I open the file with Powerpoint and the font is NOT rendered correctly:

BUT the fonts are embedded! so this wrong display should not happen.
IF I try to save the file, obviously I get the message above "Font Not Available", even if the font exists within the file.
In fact, what is strange is that in some computers this behaviour does not happen, Powerpoint works as expected. I have tested in another computer which DOES NOT have the font installed, uses the same PowerPoint version and the pptx is displayed correctly. But in a third computer, same Powerpoint version, it shows the same issue as me.
As I mentioned, the fonts that I tried CAN be embedded, they are freeware and with no licence restrictions, so it is not an issue of a font not being possible to have it embedded.



However, when I remove the font from my system


That's the key. PowerPoint can only embed fonts that are installed on your system. If it were otherwise, PowerPoint would become a free font distribution system for a lot of fonts that you normally have to pay for. The font foundries wouldn't stand for it; it'd be the end of embeddability of any sort.
Some fonts are flagged as install-embeddable, meaning once they're embedded, the font gets installed when you open the PPTX on another system; those would then be embeddable, but install-embeddable fonts are fairly rare.

The fonts are installed in my system. I save the file and I see the font embedded inside the PPTX file. It IS there. It is just not used. You misunderstood my question. I said I removed intentionally the font and tried to open the file, and the embedded font was not used. I discovered this when I tried to open a file with embedded fonts that was not working

You seem to be describing two different things. The dialog in your screenshot looks like what appears when you try to save a file with fonts embedded and PPT is unable to embed the fonts for whatever reason. Your reply above seems to be more about PPT not displaying the embedded font correctly when you open the file. Can you please clarify which it is (or if it's something else altogether)?  Thanks. (BTW, I don't understand why someone downvoted your (perfectly reasonable) question. I've upvoted it again.

Please, check my edit

Thanks for providing the file download. I mostly use the same version of PPT as you, by the way. When I open the file and run a bit of code like so ...
Sub thing()

Dim x As Long

With ActivePresentation
    Debug.Print .Fonts.Count
    For x = 1 To .Fonts.Count
        With .Fonts(x)
            Debug.Print .Name
            If .Embeddable Then
                Debug.Print "Embeddable"
            Else
                Debug.Print "NOT Embeddable"
            End If
            If .Embedded Then
                Debug.Print "Embedded"
            Else
                Debug.Print "NOT Embedded"
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With

End Sub

... PowerPoint tells me that Bryndan Write (the font in question) is embeddable and embedded.
But when I save as a new file name, it default so embedding the font, including all glyphs, but gives me the same dialog box as you're seeing.
I believe you've picked up a rock and found wigglies beneath it.
Can you provide a link to the font file(s)?
I'd like to try installing it to see what happens. And reporting this to someone I know at MS who might be able to shed more light.
And again, thanks for the clarification + PPTX file.

You can find it here: https://www.fontspace.com/bryndan-write-font-f25017   But I have the same issue with all other fonts... (or, at least, many of them)

Thanks for the font link. I installed it, used it in a PPT file and chose to save with all characters embedded. Removed the font and found the same thing as you: PPT claimed to be using it (it always does that ... call it a bug or a seriously arcane weird feature, your choice), but didn't display the text properly  or even make a reasonable substitute choice.

(Second comment to get round the character limitation in SO)
If you look at the font in File Explorer (C:\Windows\Fonts) you'll see that it's listed as Installable but that a whole bunch of other attributes are missing. That would certainly account for why the font substitution engine gives up and uses Calibri or whatever. But I'm wondering whether the lack of attributes causes PPT to refuse to use/install it when the file is re-opened.
It'd be worth testing to see which fonts exhibit this same problem and whether there's a 1:1 match with the fonts that are missing attributes.

But I find that it is not only this font, it happens also with others (if not all). Also, I discovered that I was able to get the correct result by using the XML PPT format (but not anymore for some reason).



"But I find that it is not only this font, it happens also with others (if not all)."  Well that'd be the next thing to investigate. Which ones cause this problem and which don't, then view their properties in File Manager to see if there's any commonality. If possible test with/compare properties to a font that didn't come with Windows/Office but DID come from a reliable commercial font source. Free fonts, even those from Google, aren't necessarily built to the standards MS/PPT require.


